# Stop automatic migrations when I deploy to production

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have a linq to entities application that was working great until someone tried to add a column to a database table.

I was quite surprised to see that the production application crashed because it wanted to run to automatic migration and delete the column. It stopped due to potential dataloss.

How can I have my application run and not try to sync the database up? I would like older versions of my linq to entities code first applications to run alongside the newer versions if the database changes are not breaking changes.

Comment: you still want the migrations for development?

Comment: yes the auto migrations really seem to speed up development

Comment: are you setting an initializer anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In production, you could...

- Use [`SetInitializer<YourContext>(null)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Gg679461(v=VS.113).aspx) on startup or...
- Disable database initialization using the [configuration file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Gg679461(v=VS.113).aspx)

  ```
  <contexts> 
    <context type="Namespace.MyContext, MyAssembly"
             disableDatabaseInitialization="true" /> 
  </contexts>
  ```

Either way, automatic migrations would be disabled (as would the __MigrationsHistory/metadata check...I think).